# Get the Monday and Sunday of a given week in php

Tags: php, date

Given a week of the year (20 for example)

How can I retrieve the Monday and Sunday days of this week?.

What i need to show is a string with the day range of that week, something like

```
 from dayX of monthX of 2012 to dayY of monthXY of 2012
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just playing a little with strtotime() and date() ...

```
<?php

 $week_number = 20;
 $year = 2012;
 $monday = strtotime($year."W".str_pad($week_number,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT)."1");
 $sunday = strtotime($year."W".str_pad($week_number,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT)."7");

 echo "From " . date("l", $monday) . " " . date("j", $monday) . " of " . date("F", $monday) . " of " . $year . " to " . date("l", $sunday) . " " . date("j", $sunday) . " of " . date("F", $sunday) . " of " . $year;

?>
```

Hope this was helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The fourth of January is always in week one, so once you know what week day it is you can find the Monday and Sunday of week one. Then just add seven days for each subsequent week.